# Passing query results in a viewbag

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, ef-code-first

This seems like it should be so easy, but I've tried three or four ways to do it (but to no avail).

I'm just trying to put a query result in a viewbag and display it.

I've tried putting a model object list in a ViewBag:

```
var mesg = from MSG in lemondb.Messages
where MSG.msg == Membership.GetUser().ToString()
select MSG;
ViewBag.messages = MSG;
```

And then I try to spit it out in a .cshtml:

```
var message = (List<LemonTrader.Models.Message>)ViewBag.messages;  // <--- fails here because it is a string
foreach ( var MSG in message )
{
@Html.Label(MSG.msg)<br />
}
```

But it says:

> Cannot convert type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery'
>   to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'

So it seems I'm using using the wrong template. How do I spit out a System.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery?

I've also tried passing the results through the Viewbag as a list of strings. (Is that a worse way to do it?)

```
var mesg = from MSG in lemondb.Messages
where MSG.msg == Membership.GetUser().ToString()
select MSG.msg;
ViewBag.messages = mesg;
```

And spitting it out as a string list:

```
foreach (var atext in ViewBag.messages as List<string>) { // gets hung up on foreach here (why???)
    @Html.Label( atext )   
}
```

And I get this:

> Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.

And it points at the "foreach" keyword.

Does that mean there were no messages? Or what?

I wish there was a tutorial showing how to put queryresults in a ViewBag and how to get them out! I've seen tutorials that return an object.ToList() without respect to any kind of "where" mechanism, but no examples to pull out a few, relevant entries and display them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
ViewBag.messages = MSG.ToList();
```

Also, System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery implements IEnumerable ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbquery(v=vs.103).aspx ) so this should also work:

```
var message = (IEnumerable<LemonTrader.Models.Message>)ViewBag.messages;
```

Comment: For some reason, when I used this line: "ViewBag.messages = mesg.ToList();" I got this error: "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Comment: I see this error when I do "select MSG" and "select MSG.mesg". Also got this error when I did this: "ViewBag.messages = mesg.ToString();" (instead of ToList()).

Comment: Okay, by doing ViewBag.messages = mesg, I can explicitly cast ViewBag.messages to IEnumerable<LemonTrader.Models.Message>, but I'm not sure how to display the string inside it in the html. When I try "    foreach ( var MSG in message )
        {
            @Html.Label(MSG.msg)<br />
        }" I get that "Can't do System.String ToString()" error.

Comment: When I try: "foreach( string a_mesg in message.msg ) {" I get this error: "'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<LemonTrader.Models.Message>' does not contain a definition for 'msg' " Even though my model class has a "msg" attribute.

Comment: So I can convert it to my Message type, but then when I try to do this:  var a_string = "message.First().msg;" it says it doesn't understand System.string toString()." again.