# Why is ViewBag not displaying query result correctly?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have the following in my controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id)
    {
        int projectId = (int)id;

        //Get the project name to use in the view
        var projName = from p in db.Projects where p.ID == id select p.ProjectName;
        ViewBag.projectName = projName.ToString();

//Rest of code ommitted
```

And in my view:

```
<p>There are no actors for the @ViewBag.projectName yet.</p>
```

The problem is, my view is rendering the following, instead of my project name:

There are no actors for the `SELECT [Extent1].[ProjectName] AS [ProjectName] FROM [dbo].[Project] AS [Extent1] WHERE [Extent1].[ID] = @p__linq__0` yet.

I've tried changing the code to `ViewBag.projectName = projecName.ToList();` as per this question [Passing query results in a viewbag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080759/passing-query-results-in-a-viewbag) but that renders:

`There are no actors for the System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.String]` yet.

What am I doing wrong here?

Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`projName` is currently just an `IQueryable` object as you have it now.

You need to actually EXECUTE the query against the db and save the result in the `ViewBag.projectName` property.

Switching out your `var projName = from p in db.Projects where p.ID == id select p.ProjectName;` line to the following should resolve this:

```
    var projName = db.Projects.Find(id).ProjectName;
```

(this assumes that `ID` is the primary key for `projects` - if not, use something like `db.Projects.Where(p => p.ID == id).First().Select(p=>p.ProjectName);` instead)

Comment: That worked thanks :-) You saved my Sunday. Switching out the line as you suggested meant that I could then just use `ViewBag.projectName = projName;`. (Just in case anyone else reads this in the future when having a similar issue).